# imagejpeg() doesnt give the output properly in php

Tags: php, image-processing, gd

I want to upload an image from disk, *resize it,*  and then upload it to Amazon S3.

However, I cant get the proper image output from imagejpeg().

heres my code:

```
$sourceUrl = $_FILES['path']['tmp_name'];       
$thumbWidth = '100';
$thumbid = uniqid();
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($sourceUrl);
$width = imagesx( $img );
$height = imagesy( $img );

// calculate thumbnail size
$new_width = $thumbWidth;
$new_height = floor( $height * ( $thumbWidth / $width ) );

// create a new temporary image
$tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor( $new_width, $new_height );

// copy and resize old image into new image
imagecopyresampled($tmp_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

// output the image 
imagejpeg($tmp_img);

// upload thumbnail to s3
$s3->putObjectFile($tmp_img, "mybucket", $thumbid, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ);
```

Firebug gives me this error :

```
illegal character
[Break on this error] (�����JFIF���������&gt;CREATOR: g...(using IJG JPEG v62), default quality\n
```

If I modify imagejpeg this way,

```
imagejpeg($tmp_img, 'abc.jpg');
```

then I get the same error. :(

Can i get some help here please ?

Comment: The second method you describe should work, the JPG code shouldn't be output. Are you 100% sure it doesn't? Are you echoing the contents elsewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the documentation of `imagejpeg` you can see it *outputs* the image, it means the way you call it it gets sent to the browser. You can get it to save to a file the second way you call it - by passing a filename in the second parameter.

Also, `$tmp_img` is an image resource, not a ready-to-use image file.

I don't know how your upload function works, but: if you need the *file contents* to upload, do it like this:

```
ob_start();
imagejpeg($tmp_image);
$image_contents = ob_get_clean();
$s3->putObjectFile($image_contents, "mybucket", $thumbid, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ);
```

if you need a *filename* to upload:

```
$filename = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), "foo");
imagejpeg($tmp_image, $filename);
$s3->putObjectFile($filename, "mybucket", $thumbid, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the header:

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
```

Comment: It would be the right answer if he were trying to *output* the image, but he's trying to *store* it to Amazon.

Comment: But also output it: imagejpeg($tmp_img); << imagejpeg — Output image to browser or file. If no filename has been specified then it will be displayed directly

Comment: yes, but that's what he was doing wrong (among other things).

Comment: Because of the comment "// output the image" I understood that he is trying to upload this file AND show it.

Answer (score 0):

1) `$tmp_img` is a resource not a file.  You probably need to save the image to disc and use that for `putObjectFile`

2) You probably need to tell S3 that the file you're uploading is of type image/jpeg

Answer (score 0):

Well guys thank you very much again, I screwed around a bit more and combining that with your responses I got this working as follows :)

```
$thumbid .= ".jpg";
$img = imagecreatefromgif($sourceUrl);
$width = imagesx( $img );
$height = imagesy( $img );

// calculate thumbnail size
$new_width = $thumbWidth;
$new_height = floor( $height * ( $thumbWidth / $width ) );

// create a new temporary image
$tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor( $new_width, $new_height );

// copy and resize old image into new image
imagecopyresampled($tmp_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

$path = '/var/www/1.4/wwwroot/cdn/'.$thumbid;
// output the image 
if(imagegif($tmp_img, $path)){                  
    $thumblink = "";
    // upload thumbnail to s3
    if($s3->putObjectFile($path, "mybucket", $thumbid, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ)){
        $thumblink = "http://dtzhqabcdscm.cloudfront.net/".$thumbid;
        imagedestroy($tmp_img);
    }
    return $thumblink;
}
```